# Coordinating conjunction right before a subordinate clause

Tags: commas, conjunctions

How should the following sentence be formatted?

> 1. The beagles lost the game, **but,** because of their excellent attempt, they won our hearts.
> 2. The beagles lost the game, **but** because of their excellent attempt, they won our hearts.

I'm concerned about how to use commas with a coordinating conjunction right before a subordinate clause embedded in another subordinate clause.

Comment: Putting a comma before and after _but_ puts a double intonation curve on it, which draws attention to the conjunction. If you want to stress the surprise, that's one way to do it.

Comment: It's also possible to use only a single comma in the sentence: before *but*. There doesn't have to be a comma before *they*. (Although it's common to put one there, it's not essential.)

Comment: I would omit the  comma after game: "The beagles lost the game but, because of their excellent attempt, they won our hearts". That neatly sets the interpolation off from the rest of the clause.